# Want to know, how to disabled mongodb through application.properties

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-panache

Quarkus, quarkus-panache
Need to know what property should be use to disabled mongodb instance in application.properties file. e.g:- we can use quarkus.scheduler.enabled=false to stop scheduler.
I used below way but no luck

I'm trying to write the quarkus-junit-test case, but before that I want to stop my running mongodb instance from my actual project

I tried below way just ignore dependency, which is specific to project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76JhE.png)

Comment: Why do you need to disable mongo handling?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or how to improve the quality of your question. Then edit your question to include your full source code you have as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be compiled and tested by others. Included sources [should be in text format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5043481), not an image. Currently you are not asking any question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the MongoDB instance automatically started by Quarkus in dev mode, you need to add `quarkus.mongodb.devservices.enabled=false` to your `application.properties`.